# Reg Ex to caputure between hyphens

Tags: regex

Hi trying to capture the following data to export out to another part of the program.

Ideally would use regular expressions as TOKEN could be problematic (its for names so the string would vary, especially for users abroad, I've seen these people with 4+ different names)

Sample data which I want to capture from would be in this format

```
New Starter - First Last - test
```

I'd want to capture everything between the hyphens rather than the entire thing

So far I have the following regex: `-([^-]+)-`

Which just captures

```
- First Last -
```

Comment: Im a bit unsure about what you want. So your capture you dont want the hyphens in the match itself?

Comment: Thats right, just whatever words are between the hyphens

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=-\s).+(?=\s-)
```

If you dont want something to appear in the match, but need to check its there you can use lookahead/lookbehind

More info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

This is assuming the same format will appear on all other inputs.